# User Profile issue

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, 2010

we are using 2 SharePoint farm ( 2010 and 2013). we have configured user profile on both. if we compare the no of user synced, we found huge difference.

could you explain what to check to over ride of this issue.

any query or question please ask to understand the situation.

Answer (score 1):

There are couple of things to check / compare. If both farm are on the same Domain then check

- Exclusion Filters, if you have any then both farm should have both to get same results.
- Make sure you are selecting the same OU in both connections.

How many extra you are seeing? check if disabled user listed in UPA.

Comment: in 2010 we can seen 11000+ users and in 2013 we can seen 15000+ users.